# error on require mapbox maps in titanium

Tags: android, iphone, maps, titanium, mapbox

I'm trying to add a map from mapbox on my titanium project to work with android and IOS but when e make my require like this:

```
var mapbox = require('com.polancomedia.mapbox');

var mapView = mapbox.createView({
    map: 'control-room',
    //map: 'road-trip',
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 6,
    zoom: 10,
    accessToken: 'pk.xyz.abc', //my token tha I have generated
    centerLatLng: [20.7972,-88.1598],
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL
});

win.add(mapView);
win.open();
```

It always returns an error saying:

Couldn't find module: com.polancomedia.mapbox for architecture:x86_64

Douse someone have a solution to put this working with maps from mapbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions here:

1) When doing a require on a module if the the path is wrong and it can't find the module for whatever reason you get the 64bit message which can be a bit misleading, check the path is correct and the string is using the correct casing, check for capitals and if there is a mismatch.

2) If that does not work then you need to make sure the module supports 64bit architecture. As the module could not have 64 bit support, take a look at http://gitt.io/ to find modules that have 64 bit support and if need one that isn't follow this guide to upgrade the module http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/release-notes/?version=3.5.0.RC#modules